# Custom templet of Blazor8 project causes Antiforgery cookie error

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have create a project templet from a Blazor 8 project. The project I have created the templet from works with no issues however the templet I cretaed doesnt work. Any project cretaed from the templet causes an error that appears to be releated to the antiforgery fetchers. The error

Migrate entirely to HTTPS to have cookies sent to same-site subresources

followed by

A cookie was not sent to an insecure origin from a secure context. Because this cookie would have been sent across schemes on the same site, it was not sent. This behavior enhances the SameSite attribute’s protection of user data from request forgery by network attackers.
Resolve this issue by migrating your site (as defined by the eTLD+1) entirely to HTTPS. It is also recommended to mark the cookie with the Secure attribute if that is not already the case.

the project that created the templet works fine and the project that was created from that templet appears to be fine but for this runtime error.

Any advice?

Checked all the files and all the replace's did what was expected.